# Update table with foreach in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have a model with this function

```
function dummy_system(){
    $this->db->select('SKU, size, color')
             ->from('order_detail')
             ->where('order_id',"52F4CC00C32");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    // 2nd query
    foreach($query->result() as $row):
        $SKU = $row->SKU;
        $size = $row->size;
        $color = $row->color;

        $this->db->select('stock_quantity')
                 ->from('item_stock')
                 ->join('items','items.stock_id = item_stock.stock_id')
                 ->join('item','item.item_id = items.item_id')
                 ->where('item.SKU',$SKU)
                 ->where('item_stock.size',$size)
                 ->where('item_stock.colour',$color);

        $query = $this->db->get();
    endforeach;

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
    return $query->result();
    }
    else{
        return array();
    }
}
```

this controller

```
public function index()
{
    $this->load->model('nekogear');
    $data['dummy'] = $this->nekogear->dummy_system();

    echo "<pre>";
    die(print_r($data, TRUE));
}
```

and this is the result which only showing the last query.

```
Array
(
    [dummy] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [stock_quantity] => 5
                )

        )

)
```

---

my question is how to do the foreach loop in model to get all query result with one order_id? (the current order_id has two rows with same order_id)
with this code (which I need the SKU, size & color values into the next queries)

```
$this->db->select('SKU, size, color')
             ->from('order_detail')
             ->where('order_id',"52F4CC00C32");

    $query = $this->db->get();

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->result();
    }
    else{
        return array();
    }
```

it can fetch the result

```
Array
(
    [dummy] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [SKU] => Nisekoi-01
                    [size] => L
                    [color] => Biru
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [SKU] => Wooser-01
                    [size] => XL
                    [color] => Kuning
                )

        )

)
```

---

with that in mind, I think the problem lies in the foreach loop inside my model and I don't know how to solve this.

thanks for your time and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: you could try var_dumping `$this->db->last_query();` in your foreach to see what queries it's trying to make.  You might also try calling [`enable_profiler();`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter%20/user-guide/libraries/output.html).  I think it outputs your queries.  This of course will just help you debug your queries and see if they are actually being called correctly.

Comment: @JosephMarikle, my last query result is : Array
(
    [dummy] => SELECT `stock_quantity`
FROM (`item_stock`)
JOIN `items` ON `items`.`stock_id` = `item_stock`.`stock_id`
JOIN `item` ON `item`.`item_id` = `items`.`item_id`
WHERE `item`.`SKU` =  'Wooser-01'
AND `item_stock`.`size` =  'XL'
AND `item_stock`.`colour` =  'Kuning'
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build an array and loop through it to get the stocks :

```
$this->db->select('SKU, size, color')
->from('order_detail')
->where('order_id',"52F4CC00C32");

$query = $this->db->get();
$skus = array();
foreach($query->result() as $row):
    $skus[$row->SKU] = array('sku' => $row->SKU, 'size' = $row->size, 'color' = $row->color);
endforeach;

$return = array();

foreach($skus as $sku => $data):
    $SKU = $data['sku'];
    $size = $data['size'];
    $color = $data['color'];

    // same query

    $return[] = $query->result();
endforeach:

return $return;
```

Comment: it still display only the last query. Array
(
    [dummy] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [stock_quantity] => 5
                )

        )

)